# ContentProvider vs SQlite: Same query different result

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a `ContentProvider` that uses a custom `CursorFacory` in debug to print out the SQL queries (for debugging).

A certain query was returning 0 rows, while I knew there were rows that should have been included. So I copied the query from my logs, replaced the bind values and ran it in sqlite3 shell on the device and got the correct result.

**The Query Code**

```
cr.query (contentUri, 
    Projection.columns, 
    FeedColumns.FEED_TYPE + "=? AND " +
    FeedColumns.SUB_TYPE + "=? AND " +
    ProfileUpdateFeedItem.UPDATED_FIELD + "=? AND " +
    FeedColumns.IS_NOTIFIED + "=?",
    new String[] {FeedType.USER, // 2
        WallPostData.WallPostType.PROFILE_UPDATE, // 1
        ProfileUpdateData.ProfileField.STATUS, // 0
        SQLBoolean.FALSE // 0
    }, 
    FeedColumns.CREATED + " ASC");
```

**From the logs:**

```
07-04 12:48:51.339    4067-4314/com.redacted.android D/DATABASE﹕ QUERY: SQLiteQuery: SELECT DISTINCT id, sender, data_1, data_2, photo, feed_type, sub_type, created, expiry, updated, comment_count, comment_unread, reaction_count, reaction_unread, sender_name, sender_photo, _id FROM wall WHERE feed_type=? AND sub_type=? AND data_1=? AND is_notified=? ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 100
```

**On device:**

```
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT id, sender, data_1, data_2, photo, feed_type, sub_type, created, expiry, updated, comment_count, comment_unread, reaction_count, reaction_unread, sender_name, sender_photo, _id FROM wall WHERE  feed_type=2 AND sub_type=1 AND data_1=0 AND is_notified=0 ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 100;
53b702b827d7482062f52b03|a7e759d78abe4bfa97045ce49a24ab57|0|Educ||2|1|1404502712279|1404761912325|1404502712279|||||Luke Skywalker|pr/e5c2c0398b267f93683c80dc5009722e|49
```

The ContentProvider, however, doesn't agree and `cursor.getCount()` returns 0.

Any ideas why this is happening?

*feed_type*, *sub_type*, and *is_notified* are `INTEGER` columns.

*data_1* is a `BLOB` that is storing an *integer* for any row that would qualify for this query, but stores *strings* for other types of data that could go in this table.

Comment: If you have a column that can be integer or string you need to fix your schema.

Comment: Show the code that executes the query.

Comment: @Gabe Can you elaborate? A `BLOB` is essentially free-form data that can be populated with anything.

Comment: But it shouldn't be populated by multiple different things.  That's why you have columns, including nullable ones if needed.  By keeping different types of data in one column you end up with either extremely complex querries or writing part of your queries in post-processing code.  If you had a variable in you class you wouldn't sometimes use it as a boolean and sometimes as a string.  Same goes for a column.

Comment: Could you confirm that within ContentProvider itself query returns valid values or being invoked at all? Also, it would be great to take a look at your ContentProvider source code

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev Yes, that query is fed directly to the sqlite db and it works in every case except for this one. It is a very *dumb* query. It works well when used without the above selection clauses. I'm suspecting it has to do with the blob and am changing it to an int, but it has previously worked (a feature that was removed and is now being added back. I can't revert because of a massive amount of refactoring that happened between the commits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here was the BLOB column. It was being evaluated properly in queries (The data in the table is used in a `ListView` and is displayed differently depending on the contents of the `data_1` and `data_2` columns).
Everything in the `feed` category gets parsed into a member of a class hierarchy rooted at an AnstractFeedObject.

Most fields that use both `data_1` and `data_2` store text in both, but some fields (those who correspond to a subset of the mentioned class hierarchy) use `data_1` as a type enumeration that the UI uses to interpret the value stored in `data_2`. For example, a 0 type means that `data_2` is a picture id (construct the url and download), while type 1 means it's actual text content.

What I ended up doing was that I replaced `data_1` with an integer column called `type_enumeration` and renamed `data_2` to `data_1`. Now that I know `BLOB` can cause those kinds of issues, I'll be changin `data_2` also to a `TEXT` column.

If at some point in the future I need to store binary data in the DB, I'll add a `bin_data` to the column.

Now usually in a proper normalized schema you'd use linked tables to represent such hierarchy, but in a mobile environment, you want to minimize joins so a few extra columns are cheaper in terms of performance (at least that's been my experience).

Answer (score 1):

When you run in the shell i'm surprised you get any rows.  The blob data type may not convert the keyed value properly for you. Typically the database API requires a special function to set the blob value as well as retrieve it.

Comment: That's why I decided to run it in the shell. I thought maybe the BLOB is messing things up for me. When the query ran and produced the expected results it really threw me off and I thought maybe I'm looking for a typo or logic error. According to the sqlite reference (sqlite.org/datatype3.html): BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Comment: If querying against a known value with a known data it may be best to make a separate column for that value.  If the need is to query against something within the blob the recommended approach is the read data from the blob, using the sqlite bind api for blobs, and compare the data based on whatever structure the data has.